# How to write .htaccess 301 redirect rule for

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect the following pages:

```
www.site.com/austin-tx-key-word-string
www.site.com/austin-tx-different-key-word-string
www.site.com/austin-tx-even-different-key-word-string
```

All going to this page:

```
www.site.com/austin-tx
```

Comment: do you want to redirect all urls beginning with `www.site.com/austin-tx` or just a few specific ones?

Comment: and have you tried anything?